# Selecting a specific number of characters

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have some .doc files with a lot of text, and I want to change the color of the text each 217 characters. The first 217 characters (including blank spaces) would be one color, the next 217 would be another color and so on.

BUT, I also wanted to create a condition where: If the 217 characters don't end with a period, then the selection must be reduced to the last period before 217.

For example: "The car is blue. We need to go to the". In this case, the sentence: "We need to go to the" would not be selected, because it doesn't end with a period, so the selection would be "the car is blue.", because it does end with a period.

I don't know how can I do this in Word, I'm new to VBA and I don't know if it's possible because I'm used to Excel. Can someone help me?

Comment: I didn't try any code because I don't know how Word VBA works

Comment: I just want to know how can I start writing this code.

Comment: The best way to get started with learning VBA is to simply record a macro of you doing it manually, and then look at the code and try to understand what it's doing.

Comment: Cross-posted at: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/48339-select-specific-number-characters-word-using-vba.html. For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will alternate highlighting yellow and green according to your rules. It may not be perfect, but it will get you started.

```
Public Sub HighlightText()
    
    Dim lStart As Long, lEnd As Long
    Dim r As Range
    Dim lColor As Long
    
    lStart = 0
    lEnd = 217
    lColor = wdBrightGreen
    Set r = ThisDocument.Range(lStart, lEnd)
    
    Do Until lEnd > ThisDocument.Range.Characters.Count
        'find the last period
        r.Find.Execute FindText:=".", Forward:=False
               
        'if found, record where it is
        If r.Find.Found Then
            lEnd = r.End
        Else
            Exit Do
        End If
        
        'highlight the range
        ThisDocument.Range(lStart, lEnd).HighlightColorIndex = lColor
        'set up for the next section
        lStart = lEnd
        lEnd = lEnd + 217
        
        'if you're not at the end, reset r
        If lEnd <= ThisDocument.Range.Characters.Count Then
            Set r = ThisDocument.Range(lStart, lEnd)
        End If
        
        'alternate colors
        If lColor = wdBrightGreen Then lColor = wdYellow Else lColor = wdBrightGreen
    Loop
    
    ThisDocument.Range(lStart, ThisDocument.Range.Characters.Count).HighlightColorIndex = lColor
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Dick Kusleika. Your code helped me. I created my own version since the code was returning me an error message due to the "ThisDocument.Range". I had to change to "ActiveDocument.Range". But it worked perfectly. I don't know If my code is good enough but it's working. Thanks :D